# Using a Repeater with a dynamically generated table, ie, so unknown field names

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I'm trying to produce a repeater showing amounts of money taken by various payment types into a table.

Payment types available come from a global settings file as an array, I am creating a dataTable by looping this list and extracting sales reports (there might be a more efficient way than this loop, but this is not my concern at the minute).

My question: How do I bind this to a repeater and display it when I dont necessarily know the table column names?

I've tried various methods to give the table a header row and give the columns numerical names from a `for > next` loop, but am either getting no results, or

`System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name '7'.` < or whatever number

This is where I currently am:

EDIT: JUST REALISED MY CODE WAS AWFUL, SO UPDATED:

```
        Dim paymentTable As New DataTable("paymentTable")

        For j = 0 To UBound(paymentTypes)
            Dim Type = Trim(paymentTypes(j))
            Dim headers As DataColumn = New DataColumn(j.ToString)
            paymentTable.Columns.Add(headers)
        Next

        Dim titleRow As DataRow = paymentTable.NewRow()
        For k = 0 To UBound(paymentTypes)
            Dim Type = Trim(paymentTypes(k))
            titleRow.Item(k) = Type
        Next
        paymentTable.Rows.Add(titleRow)

        Dim newRow As DataRow = paymentTable.NewRow()
        For i = 0 To UBound(paymentTypes)
            Dim Type = Trim(paymentTypes(i))
            Try
                newRow.Item(i) = '' GO OFF AND GET STUFF FROM DB

            Catch
                newRow.Item(i) = "0 "          
            End Try
        Next
        paymentTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

THIS EDITED CODE WORKS BUT I ONLY GET ONE ITEM

What I was hoping for would look something like:

```
    card    |     cash      |     paypal   ... etc (headings row)
    £250    |      £54      |      £78     ... etc (values row)
```

Obviously there're a million ways this can be done, but this makes sense for my application, which has to be expandable and contractable depending on payment types available and this whole table needs to be repeated for multiple locations (also variable depending on who's viewing, and the number of locations in the system)

Answer (score 0):

No, dont give up but just dont name columns by absolute number with no string before try

```
Dim headers As DataColumn = New DataColumn("col"+ j.ToString)
```

Comment: I did that intially, but it creates too many rows. If I bind it to a dataGrid I can see what I'm getting and it's very wrong!

Comment: I've given up, am now creating a vertical table instead!